# Loop through list elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with an unordered list built like this:

```
<ul id='shows'>
<div id='playlist_sections'>
        <li class='sect'><span class='duration'>155</span>Section 1</li>
        <li class='sect'><span class='duration'>248</span>Section 2</li>
        <li class='sect'><span class='duration'>856</span>Section 3</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is after the page loads have some jQuery code loop through all the

`<span class='duration'>248</span>`

numbers and convert the numbers into hh:mm:ss. So that 248 becomes 2:08. I think I can probably find somewhere else how to convert the seconds into hh:mm:ss, but what I don't know how to do is loop through each span element and replace it with the result of the conversion.

Thanks

Comment: your html is invalid...`DIV` can not be a direct child of `UL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
$("span").each(function(){
 var text = $(this).text();//get the currently looped span's text
 //your conversion code here 
 $(this).text(/*calculated hh:mm:ss here*/);
});
```